# Is there any way to get expiration date of private part of the certificate c#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've got a certificate and its private part. To control expiration date of private part of the certificate I need a way to check it programmatically. Private part looks like [group of files with .key extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Espx.png). Date, that I need, is stored in a file called `header.key`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the private part does not really have an expiration date.

The private part is the private key, that corresponds to the public key in the certificate.

It is legitimate to issue multiple certificates for the same private key, and this is regularly done. These certificates may have different expiration dates, be signed by different authorities, and so on.

Just use the expiration date of the certificate.